# Encode a SVG image in python like JavaScript encodeURIComponent() does

Tags: python, svg, encode

In python I need to read an svg file into a string then encode it so that I can embed it into a data URI `data:image/svg+xml,...`.

This is exactly what the JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent()` does. There is an online tool that does it perfectly as well at [URL-Encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

The problem I am experiencing is that if I link to the SVG file via `src="pic.svg"` it works fine, but if I link via `src="data:image/svg+xml,..."` where `...` is the content of pic.svg it fails. If I encode the content of the SVG file and replace `...` with the encoded version it works. But I need to do all of this in python where I generate my HTML using Jinja2.

There is so much information on StackExchange about encoding and escaping and UTF-8, but I cannot find anything specifically on my problem.

For example, the python function I need would take the following input and produce the indicated result.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="472px" height="392px" viewBox="0 0 472 392" enable-background="new 0 0 472 392" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_3">
    <path fill="#FFB564" d="M288.7,187.7c-53.7-32.6-119.8,1-119.8,1s11.6,92.6,11.4,121.4c-0.8,2-1,4.1-0.4,6.3
        c-0.2,1.2-0.6,1.7-1,1.7h1.7c1.1,3,2.9,4.3,5.8,5.3c10.9,4,21.5,6.8,33.1,7.7c3.6,0.3,7.1,0.2,10.5-0.2c1.6,1.5,4,2.4,7.1,2.1
        c13.2-1.2,28-1.9,38.6-10.3c1.7-1.4,2.7-2.7,3.1-4.7h0.8L288.7,187.7z"/>
    <polygon fill="#52E2D7" points="173.2,146.4 180.5,184 206.6,177.2 200.1,144     "/>
    <path fill="#FFFBE8" d="M222.6,133.8c0,0-17.9-15.6-5.3,39.9c0.6,2.5,19.4,3.4,19.4,3.4L222.6,133.8z"/>
    <path fill="#F9A035" d="M188.6,181.4c0,0-20.6,0-20.6,12.4c0.1,17.2,13.4,105.6,13.1,119.9c-0.2,9.3,19.1,13.6,19.1,13.6"/>
    <path fill="#FFB564" d="M200.2,93.3c0,0,9.7,50.2,11.6,48.4c2-1.8,10.8-7.9,10.8-7.9l-13.5-40.5H200.2z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFBE8" d="M184.1,123.6c0,0-12.9,24.6-10.9,22.8c2-1.8,27-2.4,27-2.4L184.1,123.6z"/>
    <path fill="#F25F68" d="M257.9,92.8c-1.5,2-3,4.1-4.4,6.3c-1.2,1.9-2.9,2.3-4.6,1.9c-1.7,3.4-3.5,6.7-5.7,9.8
        c-6.2,22.4-0.7,41.7-8.7,63.8c-1.3,3.5,0.3,0.3,2.2,2.5c5.6-3,31.1,3.5,38.7,4.2c1.7-2.3-9.1-3.3-10.3-6.6c1.4,3.9,0.2-5.2,0.2-6.1
        c0.3-2.6,0-5.5,0.3-8.1c0.7-4.6-1.4-6.4-0.8-11c1.9-14.5,3.4-29.4,3-44.1c-2.2-3.9-4.1-7.9-5.6-12.1
        C261,92.9,259.4,92.7,257.9,92.8z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
        238,171.1 245.2,109 260.4,86.9 267.7,110.8 265.1,174.8  "/>
    
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
        180.2,182.4 173.8,144 184.1,123.6 200.1,139.2 206.6,176.2   "/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M218.2,174.8c0,0-4.5-16.5-9-36.4c-4.8-21.3-9.7-43.8-9-45.1c1.3-2.6,5.4-4.8,8.9,0c2,2.7,7.9,21.6,13.5,40.5
        c6.3,21.1,12.2,42.3,11.9,40.8"/>
    <path fill="#AF3A46" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="2.4882" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M200.2,93.3c-11.6-12.2-10.4-19.2-6.6-23
        c6.6-6.6-2.8-16.6-0.9-16.8c6.6-0.6,28.6,9.6,17.3,36.9"/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M245.2,109c0,0,11.3-4.8,22.5,1.9"/>
    
        <path fill="#FFFBE8" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M200.1,139.2c0,4.7-12.2,4.7-12.2,4.7c-3.2,5.3-14.1,0-14.1,0"/>
    <path fill="#AF3A46" d="M190.9,130.3c3.4,3.3-12,3.5-12,3.5l5.1-10.2L190.9,130.3z"/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M211.8,141.6c7.7,0,11.4-6,11.4-6"/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.9763" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M169,188.8L169,188.8c43.9-21.5,94.3-16.6,119.8-1.1L277,321.9c0,0-39.9,23.2-95.2-1.1L169,188.8z"/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="4.8228" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M255.7,270.4l-2.2-32.6l-24.4-18.9L205,236.6c0.3,11.8,1.4,22.8,1.7,34.6C206.6,271.2,236,275.9,255.7,270.4z"/>
    
        <line fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="229.5" y1="219" x2="229.5" y2="246"/>
    
        <path fill="none" stroke="#AF3A46" stroke-width="3.8582" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M233.2,240.8c-1.5,0-2.9,0.3-6.8,0.4c0,0-1-0.9-0.1,5.9c2.9,0.1,4,0.2,6.9,0.2C233.2,247.4,233.2,242.5,233.2,240.8z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Result**

```
%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) --%3E%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='472px' height='392px' viewBox='0 0 472 392' enable-background='new 0 0 472 392' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cg id='Layer_3'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFB564' d='M288.7,187.7c-53.7-32.6-119.8,1-119.8,1s11.6,92.6,11.4,121.4c-0.8,2-1,4.1-0.4,6.3 c-0.2,1.2-0.6,1.7-1,1.7h1.7c1.1,3,2.9,4.3,5.8,5.3c10.9,4,21.5,6.8,33.1,7.7c3.6,0.3,7.1,0.2,10.5-0.2c1.6,1.5,4,2.4,7.1,2.1 c13.2-1.2,28-1.9,38.6-10.3c1.7-1.4,2.7-2.7,3.1-4.7h0.8L288.7,187.7z'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%2352E2D7' points='173.2,146.4 180.5,184 206.6,177.2 200.1,144 '/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFFBE8' d='M222.6,133.8c0,0-17.9-15.6-5.3,39.9c0.6,2.5,19.4,3.4,19.4,3.4L222.6,133.8z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F9A035' d='M188.6,181.4c0,0-20.6,0-20.6,12.4c0.1,17.2,13.4,105.6,13.1,119.9c-0.2,9.3,19.1,13.6,19.1,13.6'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFB564' d='M200.2,93.3c0,0,9.7,50.2,11.6,48.4c2-1.8,10.8-7.9,10.8-7.9l-13.5-40.5H200.2z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFFBE8' d='M184.1,123.6c0,0-12.9,24.6-10.9,22.8c2-1.8,27-2.4,27-2.4L184.1,123.6z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F25F68' d='M257.9,92.8c-1.5,2-3,4.1-4.4,6.3c-1.2,1.9-2.9,2.3-4.6,1.9c-1.7,3.4-3.5,6.7-5.7,9.8 c-6.2,22.4-0.7,41.7-8.7,63.8c-1.3,3.5,0.3,0.3,2.2,2.5c5.6-3,31.1,3.5,38.7,4.2c1.7-2.3-9.1-3.3-10.3-6.6c1.4,3.9,0.2-5.2,0.2-6.1 c0.3-2.6,0-5.5,0.3-8.1c0.7-4.6-1.4-6.4-0.8-11c1.9-14.5,3.4-29.4,3-44.1c-2.2-3.9-4.1-7.9-5.6-12.1 C261,92.9,259.4,92.7,257.9,92.8z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='Layer_2'%3E%3Cpolyline fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='square' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' points=' 238,171.1 245.2,109 260.4,86.9 267.7,110.8 265.1,174.8 '/%3E%3Cpolyline fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='square' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' points=' 180.2,182.4 173.8,144 184.1,123.6 200.1,139.2 206.6,176.2 '/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='square' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M218.2,174.8c0,0-4.5-16.5-9-36.4c-4.8-21.3-9.7-43.8-9-45.1c1.3-2.6,5.4-4.8,8.9,0c2,2.7,7.9,21.6,13.5,40.5 c6.3,21.1,12.2,42.3,11.9,40.8'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23AF3A46' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='2.4882' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M200.2,93.3c-11.6-12.2-10.4-19.2-6.6-23 c6.6-6.6-2.8-16.6-0.9-16.8c6.6-0.6,28.6,9.6,17.3,36.9'/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M245.2,109c0,0,11.3-4.8,22.5,1.9'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFFBE8' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M200.1,139.2c0,4.7-12.2,4.7-12.2,4.7c-3.2,5.3-14.1,0-14.1,0'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23AF3A46' d='M190.9,130.3c3.4,3.3-12,3.5-12,3.5l5.1-10.2L190.9,130.3z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M211.8,141.6c7.7,0,11.4-6,11.4-6'/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.9763' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M169,188.8L169,188.8c43.9-21.5,94.3-16.6,119.8-1.1L277,321.9c0,0-39.9,23.2-95.2-1.1L169,188.8z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='4.8228' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M255.7,270.4l-2.2-32.6l-24.4-18.9L205,236.6c0.3,11.8,1.4,22.8,1.7,34.6C206.6,271.2,236,275.9,255.7,270.4z'/%3E%3Cline fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='5' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' x1='229.5' y1='219' x2='229.5' y2='246'/%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23AF3A46' stroke-width='3.8582' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d=' M233.2,240.8c-1.5,0-2.9,0.3-6.8,0.4c0,0-1-0.9-0.1,5.9c2.9,0.1,4,0.2,6.9,0.2C233.2,247.4,233.2,242.5,233.2,240.8z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A
```

I am not really clear what this encoding is called or does, but from what I can see a few things are:

- Replace special characters with hex versions of the form `%HH`
- Convert all quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer to my own question by translating a JavaScript answer into Python. Refer to [this](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) and [this](https://bl.ocks.org/jennyknuth/222825e315d45a738ed9d6e04c7a88d0). Not sure it is the best answer, other answers welcome.

```
def svg_encode(svg):
    # Ref: https://bl.ocks.org/jennyknuth/222825e315d45a738ed9d6e04c7a88d0
    # Encode an SVG string so it can be embedded into a data URL.
    enc_chars = '"%#{}<>' # Encode these to %hex
    enc_chars_maybe = '&|[]^`;?:@=' # Add to enc_chars on exception
    svg_enc = ''
    # Translate character by character
    for c in str(svg):
        if c in enc_chars:
            if c == '"':
                svg_enc += "'"
            else:
                svg_enc += '%' + format(ord(c), "x")
        else:
            svg_enc += c
    return ' '.join(svg_enc.split()) # Compact whitespace
```

SVG is just an XML format, so SVG files are text files. If you get the text out of an SVG file into a string called `svg` say, and run the string through the above function to get `svg_enc` say, then the following data URL should work.

`'data:image/svg+xml,' + svg_enc`